# adAndroid - How to filter Points table on the basis of points?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort the points table on the basis of points. I am using `orderbyChild` but the problem is it is not sorting.

**Here is the Code**

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PointsTable");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("points");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            mList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                PT pt = dataSnapshot.getValue(PT.class);
                mList.add(pt);
                Collections.reverse(mList);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            adapter = new PointTableAdapter(PointsTable.this, mList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

**Database Structure**

[image]

Any Suggestion?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you have something printed out in the logcat? Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the message about errors. I will fix it and I have added a database Structure image. Please check it out

Comment: I cannot see any `PointsTable` node in your structure. Please add a more detailed screenshot. Besides that, please also add the content of your `PT` class.